# How to convert binary image to grey scale in opencv java

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I have a binary image as output from background subtractor method and i want to convert it to grey scale image to apply cascade classifier in it.
How can i convert binary image to grey scale?

Comment: A binary image as in one that uses only 2 colors?  I don't think you can change it to gray scale, as you cannot add more information to the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately, you can't do that (as turbo said before, the information is lost forever).

but you had an image before, that you fed into the background subtractor , didn't you ? 
use that instead.

also, the CascadeClassifier does not support masks (like you got from the background subtractor) directly.

if you want to use background subtractor to restrict the search to certain rois, you'll probably need to call findContours() on the mask, get the bounding rects for the contours, filter a bit for size, and apply the CascadeClassifier on  the remaining rois.

Comment: That is what exactly i need, i applied background subtractor first on image to extract foreground objects to limi roi but classifier needs for gray image not binary